# extension question,YiiFramework

Tags: php, yii

I use the module user
http://yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/
then open localhost/testdrive and get an error - trying to get property of non-object
on line - `array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->loginUrl,` 
did everything according to instructions from the link

Comment: No idea what this could be, but are you running PHP 5?

Comment: php from ubuntu maverick repos-s,standart lamp

Comment: it testing  site,nothing except the module

Comment: getModule('user') is returning "null", I think, probably because you didn't modify config/main.php correctly to include the 'user' module. If you post the code in your config we might be able to help you more.

Comment: yes, please post the config/main.php :D

Comment: +1 Nice Question, I have the same problem. But there is nowhere i can find the result.

Comment: I have some UserModule where loginUrl is defined static `public static $loginUrl = array("user/login");`, so it cannot be accessed with ->,  instead could be used like that: `<? Yii::app()->getModule('user');?> // Load class` and then `UserModule::$loginUrl`. However i think more convenient way is to use user _component_ not _module_, and if needed configure `loginUrl` in user component to return proper url. Why? IMO getting login url should not create instance of module, when we have lightweight user (CWebUser class) component which already has property loginUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add 'class' parameter to 'user' to configuration in main.php, ie:

```
'components'=>array(
      'user' => array(
            'class' => 'application.components.WebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl' => array('/ua/user/login'),
      )...
```

Comment: When you add this you get the following error: Alias "application.components.WebUser" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file.

Comment: My bad, default class for WebUser is CWebUser, this works when using customized WebUser class. I put it in application/components/WebUser.php and it simply inherits from CWebUser, ie.:`<?php
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
 public $isAdmin = false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this was happening to me, too. I had put the block at the end of main.php. If you put it at the beginning, the problem goes away.